# Syntax check ~/.config/mimeapps.list

Tags: mime-types, xdg-open

Is there a way of checking for syntax errors in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`?

Errors seem to be silently ignored:

1. I added `fdsobojaba` to the bottom of the file
2. I ran xdg-open on an existing file
3. There was no error in `.xsession-errors`

How do I verify `mimeapps.list`?  Or at worst, where is the definition of the file's format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, [Association between MIME types and applications specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-latest.html) is the relevant specification, but it doesn’t describe the file format in much detail. However, it defers to the [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html) for the file format; it’s not particularly explicit, but I think the

> The value is a semicolon-separated list of desktop file IDs (as defined in the desktop entry spec).

mention (regarding the format of key value pairs) is a good indication.

There is a validation tool for `.desktop` files, `desktop-file-validate`, but it can’t be used on MIME type lists because MIME types aren’t valid `.desktop` file keys.

Looking at the code, *e.g.* for [`xdg-open`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/tree/scripts/xdg-open.in#n42), shows that the file format is very simple: tools look up keys in sections, and they do that by starting at the top of the relevant file, looking for the first occurrence of the section between square brackets, then the first occurrence of the key followed by an “=” sign. So effectively, when looking for a given key in a given section, the first line matching the key which also happens to be in the right section will be used.

This has a number of consequences:

- sections can be repeated
- nonsensical lines can be present, they will be ignored
- any line not containing “=” or square brackets is effectively a comment

Answer (score 0):

The [Association between MIME types and applications specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-latest.html) is the closest I could find to a syntax definition of the file.

The syntax "section" is very sketchy indeed - e.g., there is no mention of comments.