# Comments in ~/.config/mimeapps.list

Tags: mime-types, xdg-open, file-types

I want to add comments in my `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file.

How do I do this?

Chapter and verse preferred [as errors seem to be silently ignored](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/372940/143394).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Association between MIME types and applications](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.html) defers to the [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html), which [states that](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html#comments)

> Lines beginning with a `#` and blank lines are considered comments and will be ignored, however they should be preserved across reads and writes of the desktop entry file.
>
> Comment lines are uninterpreted and may contain any character (except for LF). However, using UTF-8 for comment lines that contain characters not in ASCII is encouraged.

Comment: I emailed David Faure about this and he said:

`Since this is typically parsed with the same parser as desktop files, a line starting with a "#" will likely be intepreted as a comment.
Well, at least in the KDE implementation.`